# Calculate rank in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, rank

I've searched for my problem, but couldn't find anything that actually solved the problem for me.

I want to show a top 10 of personal records for a game. There's a player which gets points on a certain track, for every car.

Database tables:

```
player = id, playername, username 
score = id, track, car, bestscore, totalscore, player_id (foreign key to player.id)
```

What I'm trying to do is to show the top 10 scores for each track (so the best score with the best car for that track). It should look like totalscore, track, car, rank.

In my query I should be able to make an overview like this for each username, so I also have to join the tables.

So far I am trying this:

```
SELECT    player_id, totalscore, track, car,
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM      score s, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
WHERE player_id = 1
ORDER BY  totalscore DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This is just to show the top scores of player 1, but this should be "where username = 'name' of course. I am really stuck with this right now. The rank does not seem to work properly. It should show the rank of the user on every record he said.

Example:

```
Track - car - totalscore (Best) - rank    
track1 - car1 - 30 - 2 (one user has a higher score on track1)    
track2 - car2 - 20 - 5 (four users have a higher score on track2)    
track3 - car1 - 10 - 1 (this user has the highest score on track3)
```

I really have no knowledge to know how to tackle this. I hope my explanation is understandable!

Thanks in advance

edit:

```
SELECT  uo.track, uo.car, uo.totalscore, p.username, 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ui.totalscore)
FROM score ui WHERE ui.totalscore>= uo.totalscore
AND ui.track = uo.track) AS rank
FROM score uo
JOIN player p 
ON p.id = uo.player_id
WHERE p.username = 'Bose321'
GROUP BY uo.totalscore
ORDER BY totalscore DESC
```

I've been trying with another code, and this seems to get near to what I want. The only problem is that it shows all scores for all cars on one track. I just want the highest score on that track, and show the car that's used.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 3):

You seem to want to do this using variables and you want the rank by track.  So, you are close but you need to keep track of the `track` as well:

```
SELECT    player_id, totalscore, track, car,
          @curRank := if(@track = track, @curRank + 1, 1) AS rank,
          @track = track
FROM      score s cross join
          (SELECT @curRank := 0, @track := '') r
ORDER BY  track, totalscore DESC;
```

If you want a subset (such as those with the highest scores), then you can use this query as a subquery.

An alternative approach without variables is to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT player_id, totalscore, track, car,
       (select 1 + count(*)
        from score s2
        where s2.track = s.track and
              s2.totalscore > s.totalscore
       ) as rank
FROM  score s
WHERE player_id = 1
ORDER BY  totalscore DESC;
```

This handles ties slightly differently than the version using variables.  Players with the same score will have the same rank.

This version will make use of an index on `score(track, totalscore)`.

Comment: That only gives back rank 1 everywhere.

Comment: @Bose321 . . . For the first version, you need to remove the `where` clause and have the correct `order by`.  You can do the additional filtering by making this a subquery.  The last version allows you to filter and order as you like.

Comment: I've just tried your second approach, but that gives an error in PHPMyAdmin: #1054 - Unknown column 's2.score' in 'where clause'